# Trying to create sample linux mage with yocto prject but cause building error

Tags: yocto

I tried to create a Linux image based on "yocto project mega Manuel".But I got an error in building image step.

I followed the [mega Manuel](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/mega-manual/mega-manual.html).
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Error:

> aju@aju-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/poky/build$ bitbake core-image-sato
>       WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience
>   unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested
>   distribution.
>       Parsing recipes: 100% |#########################################| Time: 00:00:49
>       Parsing of 899 .bb files complete (0 cached, 899 parsed). 1330 targets, 38 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
>       NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
>        Build Configuration: BB_VERSION        = "1.28.0" BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux" NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-18.04" TARGET_SYS        = "i586-poky-linux" MACHINE           = "qemux86" DISTRO            = "poky" DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.0.3" TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 i586"
>   TARGET_FPU        = "" meta               meta-yocto
>   meta-yocto-bsp    = "jethro:331275422b2c3f326f605c23ae89eedb4e222eb5"
>
> NOTE: Preparing RunQueue NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks NOTE:
>   Executing RunQueue Tasks ERROR: oe_runmake failed ERROR: Function
>   failed: do_compile (log file is located at
>   /home/aju/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.301)
>   ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
>   /home/aju/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.301
>   Log data follows: | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile | NOTE:
>   make -j 4 | : && /bin/mkdir -p doc && {
>   PATH='/home/aju/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/build/t/wrap:'$PATH
>   && export PATH; } && /usr/bin/perl
>   /home/aju/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/automake-1.15/doc/help2man
>
> --output=doc/automake-1.15.1 automake-1.15
>       | help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.15
>       | Try`--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
>       | Makefile:3687: recipe for target 'doc/automake-1.15.1' failed
>       | make: *** [doc/automake-1.15.1] Error 255
>       | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
>       | ERROR: oe_runmake failed
>       | ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/aju/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.301)
>       ERROR: Task 403 (virtual:native:/home/aju/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb,
>   do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
>       NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 73 tasks of which 53 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
>       Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:
>        Summary: 1 task failed:   virtual:native:/home/aju/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb,
>   do_compile Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown. Summary: There
>   were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

Is it the problem with this latest version or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using such an old release of Yocto?  2.0.x was first released in 2015 and isn't supported on modern distributions.  If you *need* to use 2.0.x then you can pick a patch from a recent release to fix autoconf, but I really do recommend using 2.5 (or 2.6, due to release any day now) instead.

Comment: Actually i'm not a well expert in yocto,I just started to learn from mega Manuel provided from Yocto so i follow the primary steps which get stuck in that error.How to get 2.5 ?Is there any reference document for new users ?

Comment: I think the problem is related with Ubuntu version because in the reference Manuel for yocto supports up to `Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS)`.Is it correct ?(reference manual link `https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/ref-manual/ref-manual.html` )

Comment: 2.5 will get past that problem on Ubuntu.